# Using jquery mobile+Phonegap on android, nothing happened

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I have already successfully displayed hello world on the android screen, but every time I tried to link to jquery script the screen has a blank. But when I remove this script, I get a normal view

My full link script that give a blank screen is

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>`

Please help me how to configure jquery using phonegap. I already place it under www folder

Comment: try using a higher version of jquery... 1.6.1 maybe

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/included-demo-apps) for four examples of using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile. Instructions, videos and code are available.